# Fine Uploader получить новое имя файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Нужна помощь с Fine Uploader (https://fineuploader.com/), ситуация такова: при загрузке изображения, я на сервере переименовываю его в рандомное имя (необходимо, чтобы не перезаписать один и тот же аплоад), и мне нужно вернуть новое имя файла в json и создать

```html
<input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="НОВОЕ-ИМЯ-ФАЙЛА">
```

. Вопрос в следующем, как реализовать на Fine Uploader получение нового имени файла в ответе от сервера, как получить доступ к json-ответу сервера?

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите свой код!

Comment: Вопрос и ответ не подразумевают наличия кода с моей стороны.